# Stream only audio with RED5

Tags: audio, video-streaming, audio-streaming, red5

I have a question about red5 stream. I know that red5 provides stream video and audio but can I stream only audio? Does anyone have any tutorials for stream only audio with red5?

Thanks for reply :)!

Answer (score 1):

To stream audio-only, simply add only the Microphone to the NetStream; if you don't add a Camera, there will be no video.

There's some example code on the Adobe site: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#publish()